# Simulink example ideas

Tags: matlab, simulink

I am putting together a workshop on Simulink. I expect that most of the attendees will be sophomore undergrads or older. I expect that most of the attendees will be in a bachelor's program for electrical or mechanical engineering or computer science.

I need to think of good example problems to solve during the workshop. These are problems that I will present and solve in Simulink in front of the audience. I will also provide a `.zip` afterwards containing problem statements and solutions. What types of problems should I use? I have a few ideas already:

- PID controller for cruise control (appeal to EEs)
- Spring/damper system (appeal to MEs)
- Solar incidence calculator for rotating bodies in low-earth orbit, integrate into SolidWorks for thermal analysis (appeal to MEs)

Particularly, I don't know what I can show that will appeal to a CS major. Also, I would like to minimize the number of examples by starting with something simple and progressing rapidly into advanced territory (i.e. simple and advanced examples welcome).

Comment: This question is maybe more P.SE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interesting CS major to Simulink will indeed be more difficult. Some ideas:

- State machine (Stateflow),
- Code generation,
- Integration of legacy C code into a S-function,

They can be include in one of your other example.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it sounds like a very interesting workshop, and good luck!  I agree with Clement that a problem using Stateflow would probably appeal to CS majors.  You could model something like a transmission using Stateflow.

Another approach for CS majors might be investigating how the various optimizations in Simulink affect the generated C code.  Check out the [documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/simulink/gui/bq7cqu2-1.html) for the optimizations for some examples, you could use block reduction, signal storage reuse, loop threshold, etc.